# Pandas split one series based on another series in the same dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the below dataframe.

```
data = [
    ("flat 1 35 rosendale road, london","rosendale road"),
    ("34 hackney road, london","hackney road"),
    ("33-45 london road, london", "london road")
    
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['addr', 'street'])

             addr                           street
0   flat 1 35 rosendale road london     rosendale road
1   34 hackney road, london             hackney road
2   33-45 london road, london           london road
```

I'm trying to produce a final series that will split the text for each row in series `addr` based on series `street`, keeping only the first left split. Desired output below:

```
0    flat 1 35
1           34
2        33-45
```

So I've only managed to achieve this via looping(see below).Any suggestions on how to prevent looping (or apply using axis=1)?

```
# list comp solution
splits = pd.Series([
    row.addr.split(row.street)[0]
    for row in df.itertuples()
])
```

`pd.__version__  -> 1.2.3`

Comment: Hi Francisco, how are you achieving this with loop. That may help to suggest a better way of doing it

Comment: `def f(row):  return row.addr.split(row.street)[0]`, `df.apply(f,1)`

Comment: @wwii thank you. I wonder if this is possible to do without using apply across the rows

Comment: Did you have something in mind?

Comment: not really Just wondered if possible at all :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also achieve this without using loops.

```py
df.apply(lambda x: x['addr'].split(x['street'])[0], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
p=df['street'].str.split('\s').str.join('| ').str.cat(sep=' | ')
df.addr.str.replace(f'\s+{p}',"")



0    flat 1 35,
1           34,
2        33-45,
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do this properly, i.e. a more robust approach that works well on more varied examples, it might be worth looking at NLP methods—–machine learning for natural language processing––in particular sequence models.

I noticed there is a Python package for parsing Australian street addresses:

- [AddressNet](https://github.com/jasonrig/address-net)

Maybe there are others or you could build your own!

If anyone has other packages/tools that would be applicable I can add them to this list.

Comment: Thank you this is really helpfull.  We are plainning to use a similar strategy as above , parsing the addresses first. We still need to handle some corner cases, hence my post . We are actually considering using this lib https://github.com/openvenues/libpostal

Answer (score 1):

This would give you your intended results with the dataset, but I am unsure if this workaround is exactly works for what you need.

```
df['addr'].str.extract('(^(.*)\d+)')[0]
```

or

```
df['addr'].replace(df['street'].tolist(),'',regex=True).str.split(' , ').str[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
L = []

for k,v in zip(df.addr, df.street):
    L.append(k.split(v))

output = [v[0] for v in L]
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
def func(row):    
    last_index = row["addr"].index(row["street"])
    return row["addr"][:last_index].strip()

df.apply(lambda x : func(x), axis=1)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.